# Start Glassfish Java DB on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4, javadb

How do you start Java DB on Glassfish when Glassfish start, and on Eclipse IDE?

The software versions are as follow:

Eclipse 4.5.1 (Mars)

Glassfish 4.1 (or 4.x)

In the past there was an option in Eclipse preferences that allowed to do this.  It used to be at the following location on Eclipse:

`Window -> Preferences -> Glassfish Preferences`

That option is no longer present.

That is an alternative to do this by navigating to the Glassfish bin directory and issuing the `start-database` via command prompt.  However, I am hoping there is a more convenient and elegant solution, that I may have missed.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your own **External Tools Configurations** pointing to the **asadmin.bat** and containing the argument **start-database**.